# How can I define names of structure member variables using LLVM C++ API

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am new to LLVM. I want to create a struct like below:

```
struct abcd{
  int a,
  int c,
  int d
}
```

and my source code is listed below:

```
 structType at;
 at.setName("abcd");
 std::vector<Type*> EltTys; 
 EltTys->push_back(Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()));
 EltTys->push_back(Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()));
 EltTys->push_back(Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()));
 at.setBody(EltTys);
 ....
```

This way I can get a struct named `abcd`, but it seems that the struct only contains types. How can I define the member variable names (a ,c and d)?

I need them since we want to use this struct this way:

```
(struct abcd*)data->a = 10;
(struct abcd*)data->b = 11;
(struct abcd*)data->d = 12;
```

Comment: thank you , it is very helpful to me

Answer (score 1):

Struct fields in LLVM IR do not have names. If you're looking for type information about their fields, use the field index to access the field types via [the `elements()` method](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StructType.html#a704f9646b0850c935f3479b6586c400e).

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by wanting to do `(struct abcd*)data->a = 10;`. If you want to insert field access to the generated code, create [GEP](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#getelementptr-instruction) instructions.

By the way, instead of your snippet, you can just do:

```
Type* int_type = Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext());
StructType* at = StructType::create("abcd", int_type, int_type, int_type);
```

Since `StructType` has [convenient `create()` methods for creating identified struct types](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StructType.html#aa683538f3d55dd3717fbc7a12595654e).

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to do this using the LLVMStructCreateNamed() and LLVMStructSetBody() functions? TIA